# How to connect an Arduino Mega 2560 rev 3 to an DAQ DEWE2-M13S

Tags: arduino, voltage, daq

I am looking for a connector for these too for ages and found nothing. For context I have a program that tells me how much voltage something has and I want to use this data and send with a PWM output to the DAQ system.

Comment: Perhaps see this https://www.dewetron.com/products/data-acquisition-hardware-chassis/mainframes/dewe2-m13s/